# Loading a Twitter Tweet button dialog in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to open up a sexy fancybox dialog with the [Twitter tweet button stuff](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) iframe style.

```
(function () {

    // Fancybox Options for IFrame
    var fancybox_params = {
        'padding': 0,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'width': 680,
        'height': 400,
        'type': 'iframe'
    };

    // Twitter
    var twitter_params = fancybox_params;
    twitter_params.title = 'Twitter';
    twitter_params.href = 'twitter.com/share?' +
        'url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button';
    $('#social_twitter').fancybox(twitter_params);

});
```

And then a little...

```
<a id="social_twitter" href="javascript:void(0)">Twa-twa-twa-tweet me homes</a>
```

I just get a loading animation. Working with [fancybox 2.0.6](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

Comment: is the twitter button "iframe" style (as explained in the twitter link of reference) or fancybox "iframe" style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put "`http://`" at the start of external URL.

But the actual problem is I think,

```
"twitter doesn't allow itself to be embedded via iframe."
```

[from @andrew_ohlmann answer](http://support.cargocollective.com/discussion/10606/embed-twitter-site-with-iframe/p1)

So that means you are not able to do it.

Comment: That's curious. [Here on the Tweet Button developer page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) at the very bottom it says... "Note in this example when the Tweet Button is clicked the Share Box will open in a new window or tab (depending on the browser). In practice though, you will likely want to include a Javascript handler to open the Share Box in a popup window instead."

Comment: @savinger, popup, window and new tab are different from iframe, iframe belongs to actual page, but the others belong to browser.

Comment: @ocanal as far as I understand he is not trying to open twitter inside an iframe but adding a twitter button inside the fancybox (twitter offers a button iframed type)

Comment: @JFK, No I don't think so, only he can say what exactly he's trying to do, but as you see he has attached fancybox to the tweet button@click, therefore, I can say that He wants to open a tweet share window inside the fancybox.